# Navigation Stack Without sensor

Tags: ros, kuka, arm-navigation, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wanted to ask if there is a way of using the navigation Stack without the sensor. As I am working on Youbot (Kuka) and we just want to do Goal Point movement using Navigation Stack.
I tried the example from the kuka-youbot website but its giving the error "/base_scan was not update" so because of this the /vel_cmd are not sent to the base to move the base to desired X,Y.

So is it possible to set the navigation stack without using the sensor.

With Regards
Ali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55609/navigation-stack-without-sensor/) by [Ali Asad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4230/ali-asad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible.

Of course, you won't have any collision avoidance and your movements will be based on dead-reckoning.
Depending on the setup, you'd probably have to remove all obvervation_sources from the costmap setup and switch the global frame to whatever your robot can provide, e.g. /odom.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3